# Deployment Options Play Framework v1.4

Tags: java, playframework, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy a web application to Tomcat v.6.0.  I know I need to be able to deploy a single file--the WAR file.  The problem is, the command that the Play documentation instructs to run, produces a directory, and not a single file.

The command:

```
play war myapp -o myapp.war
```

produces a directory called myapp.war with another directory WEB-INF which contains the directories of application, classes, framework, lib, etc.,

I am trying to deploy this to my private JVM instance of my web server.  I have tried compressing the myapp.war directory, uploading that, unpacking it, etc,. but that does not do anything.  I get a blank screen when I check my site.

I've heard I can run Play as a stand alone server like I do locally but I have Java and Play installed.  My remote host may likely not have this installed on whatever instance is serving up pages from the public_html directory.  If I were to put my application directly into the public_html directory, how can I terminal into and issue the "Play run" command to get it started?

This is the first time I've deployed a web application to a web server.

Answer (score 0):

With this command Play produces an exploded .war file, so you don't have to zip/unzip it.

Check what Tomcat documentation says [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deployment_on_Tomcat_startup) about the deployment of an exploded .war files.

Also, a blank screen may be the sign of some problems with your application startup, so you have to check Tomcat logfiles like catalina.out or localhost.log to see if there are some exceptions.